# R: creating vectors of latin/greek expression for plot titles, axis labels, or legends

Tags: r, plot, special-characters, legend, tex

I would like to merge vectors of Latin and Greek text to generate plot titles, axis labels, legend entries, etc. I have provided a trivial example below. I cannot figure out how to render the Greek letters in their native form. I have tried various combinations of `expression`, `parse`, and `apply` to the `paste` command but I have not been able to vectorize the code that readily generates mixed Latin/Greek text for the case of a single expression (e.g., `expression("A ("*alpha*")")` is suitable in the case of a single expression).

```
data<-matrix(seq(20),nrow=5,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(data)<-c("A","B","C","D")
greek<-c(" (alpha)"," (beta)"," (gamma)"," (delta)")
matplot(data)
legend(1,max(data),fill=c("black","red","green","blue"),apply(matrix(paste(colnames(data),greek,sep=""),nrow=4,ncol=1),1,expression))
```

Could you please help me with the `apply()` statement within the `legend()` statement? It requires some modification to produce the desired output (i.e., A (α), B(β), C(γ), D(δ)). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative that avoids `parse()`, and works with the example mentioned in your first comment to @mnel's nice answer:

```
greek <- c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
cnames <- paste(LETTERS[1:4], letters[1:4])

legend_expressions <- 
sapply(1:4, function(i) {
    as.expression(substitute(A (B), 
                  list(A = as.name(cnames[i]), B = as.name(greek[i]))))
})

matplot(data)
legend(1,max(data),fill=c("black","red","green","blue"),legend_expressions)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Your solution is very robust for different inputs. Could you explain why `A (B)`, `A*B`, and `A~B` work in the `substitute` statement, whereas `A B` does not? Could you also comment for the new users why the `as.` syntax is required? I read that `substitute` returns an unevaluated expression, so acting on the output of `substitute` with `as.expression` makes sense. What about `as.name`?

Comment: @user001 -- As you likely know, [this section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) of the "R Language Definition" is a good starting point for leaning about R's language elements and how to manipulate them. `substitute()` can take as its first argument any syntactically valid statement. `A B` is not "allowed" because it's syntactically valid. (Can you think of any R statement typed at the command line that has that form? I thought not!).

Comment: @user001 -- `substitute()` does not *generally* return objects of class "expression". (See the "Value" section of `?substitute`, and play around with `class(substitute())` to see what I mean: `class(substitute(x)); class(substitute(x(y))); class(substitute({x; y})); class(substitute(expression(x)))` etc.) I use `as.expression()` to coerce *whatever* it returns to an expression object. expressions are a type of vector, so `sapply()` just concatenates the several length-1 expressions into a single length-4 expression vector. See `?as.name` to learn about `as.name()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the added clarification. I ultimately decided to select your answer because it was least sensitive to changes in the format of the input (e.g., adding spaces to strings).

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `apply` create a vector of expressions.

Instead use  `parse(text = ...)`.

```
.expressions <- paste(colnames(data),greek,sep="")
legend_expressions <-parse(text = .expressions)

matplot(data)
legend(1,max(data),fill=c("black","red","green","blue"),legend_expressions)
```

[image]

If you want to include `~` within the expressions. Given your current workflow, it  would seem easiest to replace `sep = ''` with `sep = '~'` within the call to `paste`

```
.expressions <- paste(colnames(data),greek,sep="~")
legend_expressions <-parse(text = .expressions)

matplot(data)
legend(1,max(data),fill=c("black","red","green","blue"),legend_expressions)
```

[image]

It might even be clearer to use `sprintf` to form  the character strings which will become your expression vector.

If you want to include character strings that include spaces, you will need to wrap these strings in quotation marks within the string. For example.

```
greek <- c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
other_stuff <- c('hello world','again this','and again','hello')

.expressions <- mapply(sprintf, colnames(data), other_stuff, greek, 
                       MoreArgs = list(fmt = '"%s %s"~(%s)'))

.expressions  
##                           A                           B                           C                           D 
## "\"A hello world\"~(alpha)"   "\"B again this\"~(beta)"   "\"C and again\"~(gamma)"       "\"D hello\"~(delta)" 

 legend_expressions <-parse(text = .expressions)

matplot(data)
legend(1,max(data),fill=c("black","red","green","blue"),legend_expressions)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful solution. Could you tell me how spaces could be incorporated in the labels without explicitly using `~` characters? For instance, redefining `colnames(data)` to `c("A~a","B~b","C~c","D~d")` is acceptable whereas redefining to `c("A a","B b","C c","D d")` is not (using the latter definition gives an `unexpected symbol` error when executing the `parse` statement). Perhaps if I don't want the tilde characters in the column names, I should use a string substitution function to replace all spaces with tildes before the `parse` statement?

Comment: Thanks @mnel. I want to be able to include spaces in the `colnames` (e.g., "A a" instead of "A"). However, the `parse` statement fails when `colnames` includes a space. If the space is replaced with a tilde (e.g., "A~a" instead of "A a"), then `parse` statement no longer fails. Using `~` as the `sep` in `paste` still does not work for a `colname` with a space like "A a".

Comment: colnames without spaces are non syntatic and thus I would not be a good idea to try and set these as the colnames for your `matrix` or `data.frame`. I think my `mapply(sprintf,...)` solution would be the easiest to implement this with.

Comment: The trick to get them to work with expressions is to wrap them in quotation marks within the string. This is now implemented

Comment: Ah, including quotes in the string before submitting to parse -- great idea. I have found another wrinkle: what if I want one of the labels to lack a Greek letter? Changing `greek` to `c("", "beta", "gamma", "delta")` causes the code to fail again. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: In this case you would have to replace in the character string. something like `gsub(x= .expressions,'~\\(\\)', '')`