# Greek letters in legend in R

Tags: r, expression, legend

I want to have three curves on the same plot with different parameter alpha.

```
curve(sin(x), from = 1, to = 3, lty = 1, ylim = c(-1, 1))
curve(sin(2 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 2)    
curve(sin(3 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 3)
legend("topright", legend = expression(paste(alpha, " = ", c(1, 2, 3))), lty = 1:3)
```

In the legend, I want to have three lines with alplha = 1, alpha = 2, alpha = 3. How do I make it correct?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better, looped answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169318/r-creating-vectors-of-latin-greek-expression-for-plot-titles-axis-labels-or-l) and user20650.

**Solution with sapply**

The `expression` function is quite tricky but in conjunction with `substitute` you can use `sapply` to loop:

```
curve(sin(x), from = 1, to = 3, lty = 1, ylim = c(-1, 1))
curve(sin(2 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 2)    
curve(sin(3 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 3)
legend("topright",
       legend = sapply(1:3, function(x) as.expression(substitute(alpha == B,
                                                                 list(B = as.name(x))))),
       lty = 1:3)
```

**Simple Fix**

```
curve(sin(x), from = 1, to = 3, lty = 1, ylim = c(-1, 1))
curve(sin(2 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 2)    
curve(sin(3 * x), add = TRUE, lty = 3)
legend("topright", legend = c(expression(paste(alpha, " = ", 1)),
                              expression(paste(alpha, " = ", 2)),
                              expression(paste(alpha, " = ", 3))), lty = 1:3)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a more automatic way? My real plot has more lines and I have a lot of these plots.

Comment: I prefer `legend("topright", legend = as.expression(lapply(1:3, function(x) bquote(alpha==.(x)))), lty = 1:3)`